# how to update appcache html5 programaticly

Tags: javascript, html, html5-appcache

I'm building HTML5 application, this application get data from Web Server in XML form.

XML contains images tags like "http://images.somedomain.com/large/9998463102.png" and I need to cache those images which i don't known its names in Appcache file to be available in offline mode.

Note that the images updates frequently and i can't guess the names of images to set it manually in Appcache file.

**My Appcache file look like this:**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#Version 2.3.6

CACHE:
http://images.somedomain.com/large/9998463102.jpg
http://images.somedomain.com/large/9998453193.jpg

# always load online resources like ads
NETWORK:
*
```

**The Question is** How to set images in `Appcache` file programmatically.
Note : **I'm using JS and HTML5** i don't need to use any server scripting language.